# @babel/runtime: SyntaxError: Unexpected token export @babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

two different checkouts of **same** code resulting in two different versions of **@babel/runtime** for the **same** version of babel

one version of @babel/runtime is "7.6.3" which contains *commonJS* module exports

but another version of it is "7.9.2" which contains *ES2015* module exports [this one is causing issue]

```
  export default function _extends() {
  ^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
      at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/Users/justdial/Desktop/NewT/microsite-b2b/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
      at Object.call (/Users/<abs-path>/server/webpack:/external "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends":1:18)
      at r (/Users/<abs-path>/server/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:25:22)
```

Comment: Are you transpiling your node_modules?

Comment: No we are not transpiling them